# Site has propagated on all browsers except Chrome?

Tags: web-hosting, server, browsers

I've switched a sites nameservers to a new host with a new site. This has worked fine on FireFox and Safari but Chrome still shows the old site. Obviously I have cleared the cache but the problem persists.

Would anyone know what Chrome is propagating slower then other browsers on the same machine?

Comment: I dont know why, but I can confirm I have also faced the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 4):

Clearing the file cache

You've mentioned that you're cleared you cache and I have to assume that this you mean the files cache and not that of the DNS cache. As far as I know clearing the file cache and history has no impact on DNS cache that most modern browsers use today, it's also important to note that the expire time may be different in Chrome or even corrupt and that's why it's not picking up the new DNS settings.

Clearing Google Chrome's DNS Cache

> [SOURCE](https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome)
>
> Navigate to chrome://net-internals/#dns and press the "Clear host
>   cache" button.

Comment: Yep, this is a #1 issue where clearing the browser cache doesn't fix the problem. If other browsers on the computer still point to the old site, first run the console command `ipconfig /flushdns` so the OS dns cache is refreshed. Then you find Chrome still is stuck and you clear its internal dns cache.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up, I cleared my OS DNS cache by pressing `CTRl-R` to open a *run* window, then typing `CMD` to get to a command prompt and then running `ipconfig /flushdns`

Then I opened chrome and pasted this `chrome://net-internals/#dns` into the URL and clicked the "clear host cache" button.

After that, my website came up. Did not have this problem with internet explorer on the same machine. Seems to be a chrome issue.